# Loud Buzzing Alert on high CPU usage?

Tags: sound, kde

I am using Kubuntu 18.04.

When the CPU usage goes high (I hear the fans turn on), I hear this hugely irritating buzzing sound. First I thought it was some BIOS/Hardware level sound. But if I mute, the sound stops.

Also, sometimes, while the alert is playing, I suddenly see the shut down screen (30 seconds to shut down) and no matter what I do, the computer abruptly turns off (not shut down).

I cannot identify the source of the sound (Ubuntu or KDE or...) nor edit this behaviour of turning off/playing an alert.

Comment: Can you post a /var/log/syslog?

Comment: Hasn't happened in a long time. I can post it once it happens again. Or is there something in particular I should grep for (some sound, inappropriate shutdown)?